# Angular 2 going in loop when using a Promise

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-directive

Ok, I need one more time some help for an issue that I am facing with Angular2/Typescript.

Here is my simplified code:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Foo:{{getFoo("FooBar") | async}}</h1>
    `
})
export class HelloApp {

  getFoo(parameter): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(parameter));
  }

}

bootstrap(HelloApp);
```

When you try to run this, it will go in loop, freezing my browser tab until I kill it.

The following code works fine but won't do what I want since I need to pass a parameter...

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Foo:{{foo | async}}</h1>
    `
})
export class HelloApp {

  foo: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve) => resolve("foobar"));

}

bootstrap(HelloApp);
```

Any clue ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Angulars change detection, which calls `getFoo("FooBar")` at every change detection cycle.

What you should do instead is to assign the `Promise` to a field and bind to that field as shown in your working example.

Comment: Thanks for your anerr, but since I need to add a parameter to the method, I don't know how to achieve this with just a field

Comment: Hard to tell from the code in your question. I would need more context. From the example in your question I would assume that calling `this.foo = getFoo("FooBar");` in the constructor should do but I guess there is more to it.

Comment: My template is looping over a list. But then I initiated my value by looping on the same list in the constructor. At least it works, thanks !

Comment: Can you update your question with some additional code that shows what you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create several times a promise when binding using a call to `getFoo` and register on it using the `async` pipe. You should set the promise to a field to avoid this behavior and only call once the `getFoo` method to initialize the promise.